# heroku get eror after Build succeeded

Tags: node.js, heroku

i have my app on react, nodeJS, and using Mongo-Atlas.
everything works well lockaly.
when deploy to heroku i got a get eror, but i don't know why.
i see the build ended well
and i see that heroku started to run om my server
and after it got a PORT from heroku it has ca not get eror

i connect heroku to my github
https://github.com/barakformanski/shop-server-merged-with-client

and connect my app to mongo atlas
and i see the DB updating when using it lockally

this is the log from heroku:

```
    2020-10-21T15:05:34.931784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-10-22T06:46:25.182928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-10-22T06:46:39.845387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-22T06:46:42.171998+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-22T06:46:42.172020+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2020-10-22T06:46:42.172021+00:00 app[web.1]: > node serverProducts.js
2020-10-22T06:46:42.172021+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-22T06:46:42.973683+00:00 app[web.1]: app is listening on port: 5410    and connected to Mongo DB
2020-10-22T06:46:43.486235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-22T06:58:24.671605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=shop-forever.herokuapp.com request_id=c482f9b6-7372-4df1-808f-557feafe17cc fwd="31.44.142.146" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=https
2020-10-22T06:58:24.671714+00:00 app[web.1]: METHOD: GET / 404 139 - 2.848 ms
```

my server file is:

```
    const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require('util');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PREFIX = "/api";

const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 5000;
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

app.use(bodyParser.json());
const path = require("path");
const accesLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(
    path.join(__dirname, "access.log"),
    { flags: "a" }
);


const morgan = require('morgan');


const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const { stringify } = require("querystring");
const { title } = require("process");

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

const gatApiAndEmit = (socket) => {
    const respone = Date.now();
    // Emitting a new messege. will be commited by the client
    socket.emit("FromApi", respone)
}
let interval;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("שים לב! לקוח נוסף התחבר");
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(() => gatApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("שים לב! לקוח פלוני סיים התנתק");
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));


app.use(
    morgan(

        "METHOD: :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms"
    )
);
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: accesLogStream }));

// not working
app.use("/images", express.static("src/images"));



const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    quantity: Number,
    pdf_description: String,
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    Password: String,
    cellPhone: Number,
    cartId: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cart' }],
})

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    products: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductInCart' }],
    total_cash: Number
});


const ProductInCartScehma = new mongoose.Schema({
    cart: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Cart" },
    products: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    total_cash: Number,
    quantityOnCart: Number,
})


const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
const Cart = mongoose.model("Cart", CartSchema);
const ProductInCart = mongoose.model("ProductInCart", ProductInCartScehma);

function connectToDB() {
    // return mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shop', 
    return mongoose.connect(`${url}`,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }
    );
}


connectToDB().then(() => {
    server.listen(PORT, () => {

        console.log("app is listening on port:", PORT, "   and connected to Mongo DB")

app.get(`${PREFIX}/products`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log("QUERY:", req.query);
    const userSearch = req.query.search;
    console.log("userSearch:", userSearch);
    if (userSearch) {
        const filterdProducts = await Product.find(
            { title: { $regex: userSearch, $options: "i" } },
            (err, filterdProducts) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log("filterdProducts:", filterdProducts);
                console.log("got search");
                res.send(filterdProducts);
            });
    }
    else {
        console.log("res:", res);
        const productsFromDB = await Product.find();
        console.log("got products");
        console.log("products from Mongo DB:", productsFromDB);

        try {
            res.send(productsFromDB);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    };
})

app.get(`${PREFIX}/products/:id`, async (req, res) => {
  
    const productsFromDB = await Product.find();
    console.log("got products");
    console.log("products from Mongo DB:", productsFromDB);
    try {
        res.send(productsFromDB);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

i have .env

```
   port= 5000
JSON_FILE=products.json
ADMIN_PASS=123
ADMIN_EMAIL=user@user.com
DB_PASS=binyaminteck43
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://shop-forever:binyaminteck43@shop-forever.b4cza.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

and on heroku i have config var with mongoAtlas code:

```
mongodb+srv://shop-forever:binyaminteck43@shop-forever.b4cza.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

what else should i add so u can help me please?

Comment: You need to whitelist the IP address for heroku. So that it can access your DB.
IP-0.0.0.0/0. If already done.
Please give more details,as no error can be seen in screenshot of heroku log.

Comment: thank u. what do u mean by "whitelist the IP address for heroku"?

Comment: do u mean this one:
const PORT = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 5000;
?
i vave it and see on my log that heroku give me a special port.
that what u ment?

Comment: I initially meant to add IP address to mognoDB Atlas.

Comment: But now in screenshot attached it can be seen that Serve is running and also db is connected, R u still facing some error.?

Answer (score 0):

i founf my misserable problem.
i wrote a wrong name of my client file on the static line